# Получение содержимого между тегами

Tags: php

Парсю страничку с помощью Simple_html_dom и надо получить содержимое между тегами.

```
<SCRIPT>drwfl("ВолшебствО",1078318084,"12",20,"Mercenaries")</SCRIPT>
```

Подскажите как это можно реализовать!

Comment: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: Только будет ли этот код работать  если в $search_string будет отпарсенная страница и уже из нее вытягивать данные с помощью регулярки?

Comment: УХхх заработало,спасибо тебе огромное!!!!!!!

Comment: Хорошо спасибо еще раз за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения использовал? Вот должно работать.

```
$url = 'http://angelscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1078318084';
$data = gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents($url),10));
$dom_html = new simple_html_dom();
$dom_html->load($data);

$array; 
$search_string = $dom_html;

preg_match('/(?<=[Ss][Cc][Rr][Ii][Pp][Tt][>][d][r][w][f][l][(]).+?(?=[)][<][\\/][Ss])/',$search_string, $array); 
echo '<br>Здесь вывод: ';

$arguments = explode(",", $array[0]);
print_r($arguments);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: Не работает(

 $url = 'http://angelscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1078318084';
 $data = gzinflate(substr(file_get_contents($url),10));
 $dom_html = new simple_html_dom();
 $dom_html->load($data); 
 $array;
 $a = preg_match('/(?<=[S][C][R][I][P][T][>]).+?(?=[<][\\/][S])/',$dom_html, $array);
 print_r($array);

Comment: Угу именно это мне и надо,получить параметры этих функции и занести их в переменные, и потом на основе этих переменных формировать ссылку на картинки

Comment: Спасибо большое буду очень благодарен,а то мучаюсь уже с этой проблемой долго!

Comment: Тебе нужно вот примерно с этого сайта
$url = 'http://angelscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1078318084';
//через функции которые ты писал 
simple_html_dom()
$dom_html->load($data); 
и.т.д.

Находить определенные функции между тэгами и собирать их параметры?
Я сейчас попробую у себя поставить эту библиотеку simple_html_dom() и посмотреть какой код она формирует. 
Если не получится, тогда скинь этот вывод большой на какой нибудь файлообменник.

Comment: В общем у себя на сервере. Запустил. Код смотри выше. Это только для функции drwfl() если тебе для разных случаев надо то могу поабстрактней сделать.

Comment: Там где preg_match ?=[<][\\/]
надо пробовать количество обратных слешей \\ добавлять или отнимать.
Когда ты его отсюда копируешь и вставляешь в свой редактор количество обратных слешей должно быть 2.

Comment: Вот сюда можешь написать manking_work@list.ru